# report t.test value efficiently in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have 2- different groups namely, `am.0` and `am.1` and I would like to create a data frame that shows `mean(sd)` of each group as well as `diff(sd)` with it t.test sign `***`. Many thanks in advance.

```
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am)    
        
    my.mtcars <- mtcars %>%
          dplyr::group_by(am)%>%
          dplyr::summarise(
            mean = mean(mpg),
            sd = sd(mpg)); my.mtcars 
    
    my.mtcars$sd <- paste0("(", round(my.mtcars$sd,2), ")") ; my.mtcars
```

Expected Answer is a data frame

```
        am.0            am.1      diff (SD)
mpg    17.1 (3.83)  24.4 (6.17)   17.1-24.4 (SD)**
disp   ...            ...          ...
gear   ...            ...          ...
```

Where SD is the standard error of the difference between two independent samples,

```
SD = sqrt(s_1^2/n1 + s_2^2/n2)
```

Comment: what is the `SD` of the diff?

Comment: Is there a reason you need something different than `t.test(subset(mtcars,am==1,mpg), subset(mtcars,am==0,mpg))`?

Comment: @Onyambu it is the sd of the diff = difference = am.0 -am.1

Comment: @r2evans I have many variables.

Comment: You could do: `t.test(mpg~am, mtcars)`

Comment: thank you but I am looking for something like the Expected Answer.

Comment: Then do `t.test(mpg~am, mtcars) %>% broom::tidy()`

Comment: What is `17.1-24.4` in `diff`? Is it `"17.1-24.4"` as character, or is it `-7.3` as numeric?

Comment: It is numeric value (subtract)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my rather brute attempt:

```r
my_signif = function(x, digits) floor(x) + signif(x %% 1, digits)
t.test.df <- function(x,y,df)
{
  t = t.test(eval(parse(text=x))~eval(parse(text=y)), df)
  p = t$p.value
  sig = ifelse(p < 0.001,"***", ifelse(p < 0.01, "**", ifelse(p < 0.05, "*", "")))
  est1 = my_signif(t$estimate[1],2)
  est2 = my_signif(t$estimate[2],2)
  sd1 = my_signif(sd(df[[x]][df[[y]] == levels(df[[y]])[1]]),2)
  sd2 = my_signif(sd(df[[x]][df[[y]] == levels(df[[y]])[2]]),2)
  out = data.frame(a = paste0(est1, " (",sd1,")"), b = paste0(est2, " (",sd2,")"), c = paste0(est1 - est2, " (",sig,")"),row.names = x)
  colnames(out) = c(paste0(y,levels(df[[y]])[1]), paste0(y,levels(df[[y]])[2]), "diff")
  out
}
t.test.df("mpg","am",mtcars)
```

output:

```r
> t.test.df("mpg","am",mtcars)
             am0          am1       diff
mpg 17.15 (3.83) 24.39 (6.17) -7.24 (**)
```

---

Further:

```r
t.test.df2 <- function(cols,y,df) do.call(rbind,lapply(cols, function(x) t.test.df(x,y,df)))
```

output:

```r
cols = c("mpg", "disp", "gear")
t.test.df2(cols,"am",mtcars)

                 am0           am1         diff
mpg     17.15 (3.83)  24.39 (6.17)   -7.24 (**)
disp 290.38 (110.17) 143.53 (87.2) 146.85 (***)
gear     3.21 (0.42)   4.38 (0.51)  -1.17 (***)
```

Comment: I added the line belows and I got it.  Very much appreciated <3                                                                          
 my.diff = round(sqrt(sd1^2/nrow(df[df$am == 0,]) + 
                       sd2^2/nrow(df[df$am == 1,])), 2)
 out = data.frame(a = paste0(est1, " (",sd1,")"), b = paste0(est2, " (",sd2,")"), c = paste0(est1 - est2,  " (",my.diff,")" , sig), row.names = x)

Comment: Ah yes, I wasn't exactly sure what you meant by (SD), but I'm glad you worked it out!